# Cant find element because v-if is slow

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a weird annoying error. I have a `ul` that will show if an array has values, so I use `v-if`. When the array has values I want to apply some css to it. But because there is a delay between `v-if` and the element actually existing, my selector doesn't find the element.

```
    <template>
      <ul v-if="errors.length" class="error">
        <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    export default {

      data() {
        return {
          errors: [],
        }
      }

      methods: {

        validate() {
            if (someErrorCondition) {
                this.errors.push('You have an error');
                // The next call fails because .error doesn't exist yet
                $(this.$el).find('.error').css('border', 'solid 10px red');

                // Error above; $(this.$el).find('.error') is not found. Same for $('.error')
                // This is because of the v-if

                // NOTE: the second time validate is called, this works, presumably because it exists now.
            }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot use css for the border? That seems to be the simplest solution to me.

Comment: you may use https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick

Comment: @Ferrybig my example above has been simplified a bit for brevity. In reality we dont change the `ul` css when an error is found. We apply an animation (using gsap) so a css solution wont work. We need to execute js on the element in response to an error. So the element needs to exist

Comment: A simple solution is just using `v-show` instead of `v-if`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use a computed property? Did you try that yet?

Comment: @AmrNoman Thanks :D that works and its a really simple solution. If you make an answer I can accept it.